# Is there anyway to use google distance matrix API, and google places API for free?

Tags: api, matrix, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform, distance

I'm trying to embed google distance matrix api and places api in one of my assessment projects. Can someone tell me if there is anyway i can get them for free since the usage will be very low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned that the usage would be low. You get $200 in free usage for Maps, Routes, and Places every month as per the [Google maps platform pricing detail page](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing). So you could get a total of 40000 x 1000 requests free out of $200.

[image: Distance Matrix API pricing]

You would need to set up a [billing account](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#create-billing-account) in the [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing).